# Clipped elements not triggering scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Context:

- There is a scrollable container
- Inside the container there are many checkboxes

What happens:

- When checkbox is not clipped and is in focus pressing arrow keys scrolls the container as expected
- When checkbox is clipped and is in focus pressing arrow keys does not scroll the container

The reason it is clipped (sr-only) is because of accessibility. Using visibility hidden wont solve the issue.

What worked:

Finally all I could do was use

width: 0px and it worked fine

or

opacity: 0 since width: 0px didn't work for firefox.

Question:
Any idea why clipped elements don't trigger the same response, since bootstrap provides sr-only and we have used that in multiple places. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal HTML example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sure, let me try to get a Fiddle or something